# Angular2 functions

Tags: function, angular, triggers, components

Does there exists a build in function that keeps on reloading the whole component until a boolean gets true. Bacause now before I can get some data I need to wait until a user has clicked a button in another component. But there is no relationship between those 2 components.

Does someone knows a way how to do this.

thx!

Comment: what triggers a boolean to become true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a service where is create a subject/observable.
Check the link:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

check the: Parent and children communicate via a service

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of Event Emitters in components to share information so that you need not wait for a user dependent action . Also make use of Service classes in order to pass information between components.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Also if you are getting information from a http call try and use observables or promises and then use ngIf or a elvus operator to get info into the component.

More on Angular Concepts https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/

Comment: I have added exmaple of what I want is this possible?